# gradle parameter order for task method

Tags: groovy, gradle

Actually it is a more general question.
I am writing a custom plugin for my gradle project, which introduces a new task. Since it is a very simple task I don't want to write a new task class. Therefor I use the method "task" from the project to create it:

```
project.task('myTask', dependsOn: 'build') << {
    println 'Here I come!'
}
```

Now I am quite confused what the concrete parameter list of this method call looks like. Intestinal I would they it is `task(String, Map, Closure)`. But in fact there is no method overloaded with this signature. There is only a method `task(Map, String, Closure)`.

Does groovy really rearrange the actual parameters or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload used is `task(Map, String)`. (`<<` is an overloaded operator on `Task` that serves as a shorthand for `Task#doLast`.) Named arguments are desugared into a first-argument map by the Groovy compiler.